# Route Azure App Service traffic through a VM with IPSec

Tags: azure, networking

I have an Azure VM with an IPSec connection. We also have an App Service. Is it possible to route traffic from the App Service to the VM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to route traffic from the App Service to the VM with [integrating your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

The VNet Integration feature support TCP and UDP. It gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but does not grant private access to your web app from the virtual network. The common scenario where you would use VNet Integration is enabling access from your web app to a database or Azure resources running in your Azure VNet.

You can work it with Azure App Service apps and function apps. If the Azure VM in a VNet in the same region as your app. You can use **reginal VNet integration**.

Please note that there are some limitations with using reginal VNet Integration with VNets:

> - You can't reach resources across global peering connections.
> - The feature is available only from newer Azure App Service scale units that support PremiumV2 App Service plans.
> - The integration subnet can be used by only one App Service plan. The feature can't be used by Isolated plan apps that are in an App Service
>     Environment.
> - The feature requires an unused subnet that's a /27 with 32 addresses or larger in an Azure Resource Manager VNet.
> - The app and the VNet must be in the same region.
> - You can't delete a VNet with an integrated app.
> - Remove the integration before you delete the VNet.
> - You can only integrate with VNets in the same subscription as the app.
> - You can have only one regional VNet Integration per App Service plan.
> - Multiple apps in the same App Service plan can use the same VNet.
> - You can't change the subscription of an app or a plan while there's an app that's using regional VNet Integration.
> - Your app cannot resolve addresses in Azure DNS Private Zones.

If you have a **[virtual network gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways)** set up in your Azure VNet, you also could use [gateway-required VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration). You can get step by step in [this blog](https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/blog/538/site-site-vpn-integration-with-azure-web-apps-paas-4588) about Site-Site VPN Integration with Azure web apps(PAAS).